# Issue on calling Javascript function twice results called once

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project that requires a form be built.  The form has a function that sums up the columns as well as the rows.  I am strictly using HTML and JavaScript.  I am unable to get the JavaScript function called twice, once for the row and once for the column (I will actually be calling it 3 times as I need to do section totals as well). I have created different classes for the column controls that will need summed up and a different class for the row controls that will need to be summed up, hence the two different classes in the input control.  I also believe that it could be in the for loop as I commented it out and put used an alert statement and it seemed to work perfectly. See the following code:

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function CalcSum(displayIn, calcClass){
    var sum = 0;
    var displayCell = displayIn;
    className = calcClass;

    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    var args = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <=divs.length; i++){

        args.push(divs[i].value);
        val = divs[i].value;
        sum += val*1;
        document.getElementById(displayCell).value = sum;
        dollarAmount("Form1", displayCell);
    }
}
```

HTML Control:

```
<input type="text" name="ctl_001" value="" id="ctl_001" class="col4txrev col4" onchange="CalcSum('T1_TOT_C4_TXREV','col4txrev');CalcSum('T1_TOT_C4','col4');" style= "width: 100%">
```

Comment: Probably not relevant, but `i <= divs.length` should be `i < divs.length`.

Comment: divs.length is 0 maybe

Comment: If `divs[i]` is a `div` element, then it does not have a `value` property. Seems not right.

Comment: what makes you think it's only running once? of course it's running twice but the second time is overwriting the changes from the first time. did you expect it to append the value rather than change it?

Comment: How many alert boxes come up when you put an alert before the `for` loop?

Comment: It is best practice to avoid putting too much script in the attributes of an element.  Instead, move your code a new function and have that call CalSum multiple times.

Comment: Even better would be to dynamically add the onChange event listener, [inline javascript is bad](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting), you know

Comment: If you support es6 use `for (let div of divs) {...}`

Comment: @fibono when I put the alert at before the for loop it only gives the alert once.

Comment: @vbguyny If you look at the CalcSum('T1_TOT_C4_TXREV','col4txrev');  The first item is the name of the cell the sum total will display in the second is the class of items to sum.  I was putting those in the element so as to not have a bunch of if statements (would this be better?).

Comment: How would I go about dynamically adding the onChange event listener?  Can you give me details pls. @JohannesB

Comment: @bfreed49 Your script has multiple errors. Thats why its not getting called on the second time. I have given few recommendations below and correct the errors. Then you will get your script called twice.

Comment: @bfreed49 I have corrected your code and put some dummy elements to make sure its called twice. Have a look below.

Comment: @bfreed, there are two methods to do so, see [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp). The first one is `element.onchange=function(){ CalcSum(..); }`. The second is `element.addEventListener("change", function(){ CalcSum(..); }`. With `element` being the element you want to add it to.

Comment: Note that in your case you could probably write one loop to add the onchange event to all relevant text fields, hence not having to write lots of individual onchange event listeners, which is a waste of resources (disk space/download size) and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your script technically and functionally based on my understanding of your question.

I have corrected the errors and can see the console printing the log twice when they called.

**Note**: Anyways, don't call the function twice from the inline attribute. Create another function which will do the same and call it from the `onchange` event (or) create the `onchange` listener programmatically.

1. When looping the elements, condition should be `i < divs.length` and
   not `i <= divs.length`
2. To find a text inside the `div`, it should be `innerHTML` as below
   and not `value`. `value` can be used for the form input elements
   which values can be changed by the end users.
3. To calculate the `sum`, the value should be converted to a number
   using either `parseInt` or `parseFloat` since the `text/value` of
   the element is generally a text.
4. If you have to assign the final value of the `sum` to another `div`
   element and call another method, it should be outside the `for`
   loop. But if you really need this to set/call for each loop, then it
   can be inside the `for` loop.

```js
function CalcSum(displayIn, calcClass){
    var sum = 0;
    var displayCell = displayIn;
    var className = calcClass;
  
  console.log('called');

    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    var args = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){

        //args.push(divs[i].value);
        var val = divs[i].innerHTML;
        args.push(val);
        sum += parseInt(val) * 1;  // It can be parseFloat
    }
  
    document.getElementById(displayCell).value = sum;
    dollarAmount("Form1", displayCell);
}

// dummy function
function dollarAmount(form, elm){
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="ctl_001" value="" id="ctl_001" class="col4txrev col4" onchange="CalcSum('T1_TOT_C4_TXREV','col4txrev');CalcSum('T1_TOT_C4','col4');" style= "width: 100%">

<div class="col4txrev">10</div>
<div id="T1_TOT_C4_TXREV"></div>
<div class="col4">20</div>
<div id="T1_TOT_C4"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!  It works.  I wasn't able to use the `innerHTML` though; it had to be `value` as these are not `div` tags, but `input` controls.  div was just the variable name I uses as I was copying from something else.  Thanks again!!